# How to migrate a GeoServer setup to Tomcat?

Tags: openlayers-2, geoserver, tomcat

I have some problems with Tomcat/GeoServer. I was able to create project in stand-alone GeoServer and all works fine.

This is my code.

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
 pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
  <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
   "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"> 
<title> My first JSP </title> 
<link href="http://localhost:8080/geoserver/openlayers/theme/default/style.css"type="text/css"/>
<style type="text/css">
    div.list {background-color:#dddddd; border-right:2px dashed #717dc9; width:250px; height:400px; float:right; margin-top:-395px}
    div.ol {background-color:#ffffff; height:400px; min-width:380px; max-width:3800px; margin-right:260px; padding-right:20px;margin-top:-15px}
    div.info {background-color:#eeeeee; height:220px; margin-top:10px; width:100%}
    div.upload{background-color:#ffffff; height:190px; width:300px; float: right; margin-left:10px; margin:10px }
    div.accept{background-color:#ffffff; height:190px; width:300px; float: left; margin-left:10px; margin:10px }
    div.filelist {overflow: auto; height:330px; margin-left:10px}
    div.listtitle {margin-left:10px; background-color:#ffffff}
    /* General settings */
        body {
            font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
            font-size: small;
            }
    /* The map and the location bar */
        #map {
            clear: both;
            position: relative;
            width: 687px;
            height: 330px;
            border: 1px solid black;
            }
</style>
<script src="OpenLayers/OpenLayers.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
        var lon = 150;
        var params;
        var lat = 50;
        var zoom = 6;
        var map, layer;
        var extend = new OpenLayers.Bounds(1622287.25, 383562.90625, 1623662.375, 384223.21875);
        var options = { 
                maxResolution: 5.37158203125,
                                 maxExtent: extend,
                projection:"EPSG:70066",
                units:'m'}
        function init(){
            map = new OpenLayers.Map( 'map', options);
            layer = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS( "OpenLayers WMS",
                    "http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wms", {layers: 'cite:filedata'} );
            map.addLayer(layer);
            map.zoomToExtent(extend);
    //        <!--map.setCenter(extend.getCenterLonLat(), map.getZoomForExtent(extend));-->
            map.addControl( new OpenLayers.Control.LayerSwitcher() );

        }
   </script>
</head>
<body onload="init()">

<div class="ol"> <div id="map"></div> </div>
</body>
</html>
```

But when I try to put this in Tomcat nothing happens and I don't see a map. What do I need to do with Tomcat to run project which uses GeoServer?

I know my English is terrible.

Comment: did you copy the data directory from the jetty GeoServer to the Tomcat GeoServer?

Comment: yes im cope OpenLayers directory in directory with project in tomcat. And create same layer with same parametrs in tomcat's geoserver.

Comment: Also if im launch geoserver in tomcat that geoserver works fine, but project which uses geoserver dont display my map.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I can see you  used projection 70066 and it looks like you faced with projection issue. Check Declared SRS and Lat/Lon Bounding Box options of your layer.

Comment: Tnx. That was the problem, I forgot to add my projection in tomcat's geoserver.